# Why does my Xbox keep signing me out?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-network

Whenever I start a game, from both the disc and hard drive, my Xbox will say "*Username* signed out". What's wrong and how do I fix it? Just to be clear, it signs me out when I start a game. How can I stop this?

Comment: Does it happen only if you start Terraria or Halo Reach? If not, you should remove those tags from your question

Comment: @Nolonar I edit my question.

Comment: Does it prompt you to download updates?

Comment: @TZHX No, prompts, but it does say something about NAT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some research I found a solution.
1. Delete your profile.
(Settings >> System Settings >> Storage >> Hard Drive >> Profiles >> *username* >> Delete >> Profile only)
2. Clear you System Cache 3 times.
(Settings >> System Settings >> Storage >> Highlight Hard Drive >> Press Y >> Clear System Cache >> Yes)
3. Re-download your profile.
(Press Xbox Guide Button >> Download Profile >> Enter your Microsoft E-Mail >> Enter your Microsoft Password >> Done)
See [Taidara's](http://forums.xbox.com/xbox_forums/xbox_support/f/9/t/508051.aspx#4777950) Answer For More Information.

Comment: I don't get this, this user said in the comments of an answer above that the solution worked, but there's also an answer here by that same user.

Comment: @JimJones They then later said "Ok, this worked for THAT day, now it's happening with any game I start to play." So this must have fixed it for good.

Answer (score 8):

It sounds like you've refused an **Xbox Live Update** at some point.

You can go into your system options and see if there's an update available.

To check for an update on the Xbox 360 you basically force a new Xbox Live connection:

1. Press the Guide button (center logo button), bringing up the pop-up menu
2. Go to Settings
3. Select System Settings
4. Select Network Settings
5. Select Wired Network or the name of your wireless network if you're on wifi
6. Select Test Xbox Live Connection
7. Select Yes if prompted to update. If you're not prompted and the test completes successfully, you have the most recent update.

You can also get console updates on the 360 through game discs with them, USB drives, or CDs and DVDs burned with the updates, but the above instructions are by far the easiest and should apply to most cases.

---

To check for an update on the Xbox One (since it has the same problem):

1. Go to the Home screen
2. Press the Menu button (where the "start" button is on other systems)
3. Select "Settings" from the popup menu
4. Select "System"
5. Select the update option if it's available. It will say "No update available" if you're offline or you have the newest update.

---

Source: The xbox support system and personal experience

Comment: Just for the sake of the answer, please explain how to check for an update.

Comment: Ok, this worked for THAT day, now it's happening with any game I start to play.

Comment: I think there was another update... do you have your system set to auto-accept updates? If not you'll have to manually re-update when there's a new one.

Answer (score 1):

After it signs me out the first time, I just go straight to download profile. Then I select my profile without having to delete it first. Problem is that once you shut off the power to your console it may or may not start over again the next time you power it back on . The last time I went through 10 days of powering on and off before the issue returned.